# What is the solution set of $x-(1/x)\le 0$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

The above inequality is from my maths textbook which has + in middle. Can you also tell me a ebook which discusses equations. I am just familiar with normal inequality and a student of 9th standard. I just learned about probability and inequality.

Comment: What have you tried? Are you familiar with how to manipulate inequalities in the same way as equalities, by for example moving the $1/x$ to the other side?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rewrite$$x\le\frac1x.$$
For sure, $x\ne0$. Then assume $x>0$, so that you can transform as
$$x^2\le1,$$
or, taking the positive square root
$$x\le1.$$
Now, assume $x<0$, so that
$$x^2\ge1,$$
or, taking the negative square root,
$$x\le-1.$$
The complete solution is $$x\le-1\lor 0<x\le1.$$

Answer (score 2):

\begin{align*}
x - \frac{1}{x} & \leq 0\\
\frac{x^2 - 1}{x} & \leq 0\\
\frac{(x + 1)(x - 1)}{x} & \leq 0
\end{align*}

The expression on the left hand side is equal to zero when $x = \pm 1$ and undefined when $x = 0$.  It can only change sign at $x = -1, 0, 1$.  To determine when it is negative, determine the sign of the expression in the intervals $(-\infty, -1)$, $(-1, 0)$, $(0, 1)$, and $(1, \infty)$.  The union of the intervals in which the expression on the left hand side is negative with the set $\{1, -1\}$ is the solution.

Answer (score 1):

$x-\frac1x \le 0 \iff \frac{x^2-1}{x} \le 0 \iff (x^2-1)x \le 0$

Can you proceed from here?

Comment: Be careful.  Since the inequality is weak, $0$ is a solution to your final inequality but not to the original inequality.

Comment: @taussig i didnt understand how $x(x^2-1)<=0$ came? And how to type less than or equal to?